# How to return varchar value from a function

Tags: sql-server, function

I written the following function.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
Create FUNCTION NameFunction
(
    @eid int
)
RETURNS varchar
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @logid varchar(50);
    SELECT @logid = E.LoginId from HumanResources.Employee As E
    where E.BusinessEntityID = @eid

    RETURN  @logid

END
GO
```

When I am executing it is showing result as `a`.
But expected result is `adventure-works\terri0` 
Where I did the mistake here. Only first character coming. Need to change any thing?

Answer (score 28):

Change your `RETURN` type to include a length, at this point it is just returning 1 character:

```
RETURNS varchar(100)
```

Full code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
Create FUNCTION NameFunction
(
    @eid int
)
RETURNS varchar(100) -- or whatever length you need
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @logid varchar(50);
    SELECT @logid = E.LoginId from HumanResources.Employee As E
    where E.BusinessEntityID = @eid

    RETURN  @logid

END
GO
```

Answer (score 14):

`RETURNS varchar` should be `RETURNS varchar(50)`.

`varchar` without a length specified is interpreted as `varchar(1)` in this context (and as `varchar(30)` in the context of a `CAST`).

BTW: Scalar UDFs that do data access can be performance killers. You might want to consider at least rewriting this [as an inline TVF](http://dataeducation.com/scalar-functions-inlining-and-performance-an-entertaining-title-for-a-boring-post/) so that the optimiser has more options.